# PHP array not working, multiple

Tags: php, arrays

Here's my code:

```
function prepare_machine($variables)
{
        foreach ($variables AS $varname => $vartype)
        {
                if (isset($_REQUEST[$varname]))
                {
                        $value = $_REQUEST[$varname];
                        return do_clean($value, $vartype);
                }
                else
                        exit;
        }
}
```

It is called like this:

```
prepare_machine(array('order_by_time' => TYPE_BOOLEAN));
```

it all works fine, but if you have multiple things in the array, for examples;

```
prepare_machine(array('order_by_time' => TYPE_BOOLEAN, 'order_by_date' => TYPE_BOOLEAN));
```

it will only do anything with the first one.

Can anybody see what is wrong with my code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're doing a `return ...` when you find a match in your inner loop. That's why it only processes one.

Also, you should be using `array_key_exists($varname, $_REQUEST)` because `isset($_REQUEST[$varname])` will fail if `$_REQUEST[$varname]` is null.

Comment: Okay, so what should I do instead of the return?

Comment: You need to ask why `prepare_machine()` returns what `do_clean()` returns. Whatever that answer is, you will need to re-engineer your code. Either `prepare_machine()` can't process more than one variable per call, or `do_clean()` needs to not return a "cleaned" value.

Answer (score 0):

`return` returns whatever you give it, and exits the function. You need to change your function somehow so that it only `return`s after processing all the variables.

Comment: How would I do that, then?
Thanks